# SQL Server - Partitioning table on varchar column contain datetime value without altering column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

Partitioning table on varchar datetime valued column without altering column. Find below screenshot for the structure of table.

Sample table structure

[image]

Comment: By far the biggest issue is right here " varchar datetime valued column". Why are you storing dates as strings? You should store datetime values in the datetime datatype, that is the point of having datatypes. But what is your question?

Comment: You could either partition on the first four characters, which theoretically should always be your year, or convert the varchar field back to a datetime field then partition based on a DATEPART(Year, function.  Both have their drawbacks, but if you have to work with what you got, those are the only ways I see to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Partition based on first four characters is works for me. Thanks @ChadEstes

Comment: @[Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange), for some reason I can't alter the column from varchar to datetime. It will affect other process.

Comment: @KarthikeyanGowtham all the more reason why you should change it. Keeping the wrong thing because fixing it will mean revealing the problems it creates on other things is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: [@Zohar Peled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3094533/zohar-peled) finally I changed the column to datetime format and partition is works for me. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Altering column to datetime is the finest solution for create partition based on datetime column.

```
    alter table <table_name>
    alter column <column_name> datetime;
```

Need to create  partition for datetime column is the finest way for creating partition based on datetime column for the table.